# Vue send request when declared params changed from empty string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

In my app I'm sending a request to my backend app from which I get a response with id like `{ 'id': '12345'}`. I saves this `id` as `loadId` inside data, here:

```js
export default {
  name: 'SyncProducts',
  data() {
    return {
      loadId: '',
```

Now I want to send another POST `fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest` when this data `loadId` change from empty. How to do so?

Below my code:

`imports.js`

```js
const createApparelMagicProductsRequest = (self, products) => {
  const jwtToken = self.$store.state.idToken;
  console.log(products)
  console.log()
  const payload = JSON.stringify({ product_codes: products['product_codes'].split(',') })

  return axios
    .post(`/api/v1/imports/products_batches`, payload,{
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.data['id'])
};

const fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest = (token, id) => {
  return axios
    .get(`/api/v1/imports/products_batches`, {
      params: { id: id },
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.data['result']
    })
};
```

`sync_products.vue`

```html
<script>

import {
  fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest,
  createApparelMagicProductsRequest
} from '../../api/imports'

export default {
  name: 'SyncProducts',
  data() {
    return {
      styleCodes: [],
      fetchedProductSyncResult: [],
      loadId: '',
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    await fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest(this, load.id)
    this.syncedProductsFetched = true
    this.pageChanged(this.currentPage)
  },
  async mounted() {
    const jwtToken = this.$store.state.idToken;
    fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest(jwtToken).then(data => {
      this.fetchedProductSyncResult = data
    })
  },


</script>
```

Comment: You have two `mounted` hooks declared, but that's probably a copy-paste error.

Comment: @mr_muscle You can make it simple by calling `fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest` method inside success promise of get request. i.e. If id will be there in the GET request response. Call this `fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest`.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I have no idea what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#watch) on `loadId` that calls `fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest()` with the new value if it's changed from an empty string to a non-empty string:

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    loadId(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (!oldValue && newValue) {
        const jwtToken = this.$store.state.idToken;
        fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest(jwtToken, newValue).then(data => {
          this.fetchedProductSyncResult = data
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-fetch-data-on-prop-change?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)